# How do I create a data frame of 2 columns from a list?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I want to create a data frame of 2 columns from a list.
The list contains: States and Region names by order
The States are the ones with 'edit' infront of their names, and the other words are region names
for exemple here the state is alabama and her regions names are Auburn, Florence, ... until we reach the second state which is 'Alaska'.

```
['Alabama[edit]',
 'Auburn',
 'Florence',
 'Jacksonville',
 'Livingston',
 'Montevallo',
 'Troy',
 'Tuscaloosa',
 'Tuskegee',
 'Alaska[edit]',
 'Fairbanks',
 'Arizona[edit]',
 'Flagstaff',
 'Tempe',
 'Tucson',
 'Arkansas[edit]',
 'Arkadelphia',
....
```

And the data frame columns will be States and Region names.

[image]

Here is my code :

```
    for i in range(len(list)):
    if 'edit' in list[i]:
        university['state'][i:]=re.sub('\[.+','',list[i])
    else:
        university['regionName'][i]=list[i]
```

Comment: Please add what is the list like, a small sample, and what is the expected output, also with an example. If you have some code, please, add it as well.

Comment: Cool. Do it. What hinders you?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: Dear Daniel, I have adjusted the output like you asked.

Comment: @AhmedFnayou, you Should accept this answer by clicking on the grayed-out tick mark to mark it accepted at the left hand side.

Comment: @pygo like that ?

Comment: @AhmedFnayou, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preprocess the information to make a list tuples of `(state,region)` names. Use this to construct the DataFrame

```
names =  ['Alabama[edit]',
          'Auburn',
          'Florence',
          'Jacksonville',
          'Livingston',
          'Montevallo',
          'Troy',
          'Tuscaloosa',
          'Tuskegee',
          'Alaska[edit]',
          'Fairbanks',
          'Arizona[edit]',
          'Flagstaff',
          'Tempe',
          'Tucson',
          'Arkansas[edit]',
          'Arkadelphia']


data = []
state = None
for name in names:
    name = name.strip()
    if name.endswith('[edit]'):
        state = name[:-6]
        continue
    if not state:     # In case the first name of the list is not a state
        state = 'Unknown'
    data.append((state,name))

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

---

```
>>> df
           0             1
0    Alabama        Auburn
1    Alabama      Florence
2    Alabama  Jacksonville
3    Alabama    Livingston
4    Alabama    Montevallo
5    Alabama          Troy
6    Alabama    Tuscaloosa
7    Alabama      Tuskegee
8     Alaska     Fairbanks
9    Arizona     Flagstaff
10   Arizona         Tempe
11   Arizona        Tucson
12  Arkansas   Arkadelphia
```